# Is base64_encode a secure option send details to a api with a Ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can someone let me know the best way to send details to a api using php and jquery, problem i have is someone could just view the source code obviously and see the username and password.

Here is what i have.

```
<?php
    $username = "bob";
    $password = "Changme";
    $details = base64_encode("$username:$password");
?>

var sendData = {
    "data": "<?php echo $details; ?>"
}
$.post("https://example.com/login", sendData, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, 'json');
```

Then do something in the api call like.

```
function login_post() {

        if (!$this -> post('Username') && !$this -> post('Password') ) {
            $this -> response(array('error' => 'Error'), 404);
        }

        // Check if the user details are correct 
        $data = base64_decode($_POST['data']);

    }
```

What is the best way to do this securely and simply i understand that even with this someone can just grab the base encoded string and decode it with php.

Shall i send through some kind of expiry timestamp or shall i send so unique password, just really trying to think of the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't help i am looking into https://secure.php.net/openssl_encrypt might be the answer

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Why don't you use sessions instead?

Comment: base64 is _not_ a way of encrypting data. Sending base64 encoded data is as unsecure as sending it plain text.

Comment: Thanks i guess the only way is like suggested below

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can securely protect username and password from the webbrowser which is relaying that information to 3rd party (example.com) unless you and that 3rd party has exchanged encryption keys beforehand.

You have a few options. I can think of 2:

1. Make a client serverside in PHP, and request data from 3rd party from webbrowser via server (AJAX) to 3rd party (curl, guzzle, etc). Basically a serverside proxy for that 3rd party website.
2. Log into the 3rd party website with PHP serverside, then provide an access token to the webbrowser for a one time use only with a time limit. This requires the 3rd party side to support this.

Comment: Hi @OIS so the best way would be to use a curl post to a login call on the 3rd party site get a access token and then just use this to make ajax calls? Or post to a internal php script via ajax to retrieve the data

Comment: If the 3rd party site already supports login via an access token or similar to how openid did it you can probably use that. - If not then go for option 1. Save the session cookie from the 3rd party website in that users session on your server.